# Simple Tween local copy using Scroll Magic not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

Good day!

I'm trying to make [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Phenelo/yjqtvvas/) of simple tween using scrollmagic.js. Yeah, it works on jsfiddle. To be sure, I put scene.addIndicators() to see the start, end and the trigger hook. It works clean. As you can see in the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="container" style="height:1000px;">
    <div class="spacer" style="height:400px;">
        Scroll Down
    </div>
    <div id="trigger1"></div>
    <div id="animate1">Hello World!</div>    
</div>
```

I tried changing the height of the container and spacer to any large value still the trigger hook is in the center. That's good. Now I tried creating a copy of it in my local using Sublime. But now my problem is that when I set the spacer or to a large value, I can see the trigger hook at the bottom of the page. That would make it impossible for the tween animations to be seen. Is there someone who encountered this problem? I think there is something wrong with my local setup since it works on jsfiddle. I've already asked this to the [scrollmagic contributor](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic). Why does this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved here: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/148